# How to create PFX file to use in Bit.IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bit-framework

I'm using [Bit.IdentityService](https://github.com/bit-foundation/bit-framework) to protect my resources. In order To do that I need a pfx file.
I can copy the `IdentityServerCertificate.pfx` file from the [sample project](https://github.com/bit-foundation/ToDoLine) provided by bit-foundation in my own project and use it.
However instead of using that file, I want to create a pfx file myself with a password other than the one used in sample project.
What tools/approaches/solutions are there to create a pfx file, **compatible with bit-framework**?
Up to now, I've gone through steps in [this article](https://benjii.me/2017/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-identity-server-azure/), but it ended in an error telling that size of sign key is not valid. By compatible, I mean an approach that is tested and does not end in such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run following commands in PowerShell with desired password and file path for your pfx file:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "IdentityServerCN" -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" -HashAlgorithm "SHA512" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)
Export-PfxCertificate -cert ('Cert:\LocalMachine\My\' + $cert.thumbprint) -FilePath PATH_TO_YOUR_IdentityServerCertificate.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "YOUR_PASSWORD" -Force -AsPlainText)
```

Then provide a new password in environments.json or appsettings.json file.

Comment: this worked for me. But I had to run power shell in administrator mode.